# Creating multiple objects become None python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create multiple graph and using Dijkstra's. However I'm getting an error: NoneType object has no attribute 'set_distance'. The very strange thing is that the first item in the list ['2001A1'] runs fine but then when the list is longer than 1 it just crashes with that error. If I run the code with just one item in the list, it works as well. Printing out my vertices, the graph shows that there are vertex instances for all of my keys... Is there something that I'm missing? Why can't I do this more than one times? Why is it that when I try to get my vertex object I get returned null when my map of vertices has key {1:(Vertex object)}?

```
def create_graph(q,y,pop,psub,a,b,c):
    a = Graph(q,y,pop,psub,a,b,c)
    for i in range(0,9):
        a.add_vertex(i)
    return a


def run_dijkstras(graph,data):
    for i in data:
        try:
            year = int(i[0:4])
            print year
        except:
            print i
        rest = i[4:]
        graph.add_edge(year,rest)

    quarter = graph.get_quarter()
    print graph.vert_dict
    print quarter
    print graph.get_vertex(quarter)
    print str(graph.get_vertex(quarter))
    dijkstra(graph,graph.get_vertex(quarter))
    target = graph.get_vertex(quarter+4)
    path = [target.get_id()]
    shortest(target, path)
    if len(path) == 1:
        path = "NULL"
    return [path,(str(target.get_distance())),data]

i = 2001
for j in range(1,5):
        for datacombo in ([['2001A1'], ['2001R4']]):
            a = run_dijkstras(create_graph(j,i,10,1,.05,-.1,-.5),datacombo)
            result,score = a[0],a[1]
            if score == 9999999999999:
                score = "NULL"
            score = score.ljust(15)

            datacombo = generate_matrix(datacombo)

            i = str(i).ljust(5)
            j = str(j).ljust(2)
            datacombo=re.sub("\[|\]|'","",str(datacombo)).ljust(100)
            result=re.sub("\[|\]|'","",str(result)).ljust(25)
            print(i,j,result,score,datacombo)
```

ERROR LOG:

```
{0: <__main__.Vertex instance at 0x0000000002439DC8>, 1: <__main__.Vertex instan
ce at 0x0000000002439CC8>, 2: <__main__.Vertex instance at 0x0000000002439C88>,
3: <__main__.Vertex instance at 0x0000000002439C08>, 4: <__main__.Vertex instanc
e at 0x0000000002439E48>, 5: <__main__.Vertex instance at 0x0000000002439E88>, 6
: <__main__.Vertex instance at 0x0000000002439EC8>, 7: <__main__.Vertex instance
 at 0x0000000002439F08>, 8: <__main__.Vertex instance at 0x0000000002439F48>}
1
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dijkstras3.py", line 282, in <module>
    a = run_dijkstras(create_graph(j,i,10,1,.05,-.1,-.5),datacombo)
  File "dijkstras3.py", line 190, in run_dijkstras
    dijkstra(graph,graph.get_vertex(quarter))
  File "dijkstras3.py", line 132, in dijkstra
    start.set_distance(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_distance'
```

Comment: what is this `Graph()` object you are referencing?

Comment: As well as needing to know about `Graph` the traceback says `start.set_distance(0)` but you don't seem to have shown that line

Comment: Set distance is just a method that sets self.distance of a vertex. I have two classes: vertex and graph. There's nothing complicated about set distance. Additionally, my code works for when there is one input. It just breaks when my input is more than one.

Comment: how about your `dijstra` function... that's where the error itself actually traced back to

Comment: I don't think thats where the problem is either. The program works perfectly with one input. However when I start looping it breaks on the second iteration. I printed out the dictionary of the graph with my keys and corresponding vertices. I also printed out the key I was going to get (1). I then printed the result of me getting that key and it returned None. This doesn't happen if I only put one input. Is it something related to references/pointers? Because I explicitly create the verticies in create graph. However when I try to get the vertex it returns None only for when the input list > 1

Comment: It's strange because I've implemented this before in Java and it's basically the same implementation. It just doesn't work here for some reason...